# How can I use {...this.props} in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I bought a React-Native course on Udemy and the guy who teaches React-Native used `{...this.props}`. 
But it didn't work for me. Here is the error message.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.props')

What should i do?

LoginForm.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import Input from '../components/Input';
const LoginForm: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.signInText}>SIGN IN</Text>
        <Input 
          placeholder="Username"
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  signInText:{
    fontWeight:'bold',
    marginVertical:25,
    color:'#189BDD'
  }
});

export default LoginForm;
```

Input.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
const Input: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          {...this.props}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default Input;
```

Udemy Teacher SS

Comment: Which object are you hoping `this` will be?

Comment: `this.props` is a property on a class component, this is a functional component. Props isn't defined anywhere in your component. It should be passed like `const Login = (props) => {  }`, and used as `{...props}`, not `{...this.props}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` won't exist on a functional component. In a functional component, you access props as a parameter, which you haven't passed.

```js
const Input = (props) => {

...

  <TextInput
    {...props}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create a React component: a class or a function.

`Input` here is a functional component, not a class component.

That means that the `props` are passed as an argument to your function, rather than as properties of the class instance. `this` is not used in functional components, only class components.

So decalre your functional component like this:

```
const Input = (props) => {
```

And then spread props like this:

```
{...props}
```